# How to create an autoexecute macro in excel

Tags: vba, imacros

I have a spreadsheet with data input by multiple users.
I would like to set up an autoexecute macro for all values in the spread sheet to be set to zero on the 15th and 30th of every month when users open the spreadsheet.
Please help.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Once it runs for the first user how do you intend to "remember" that you've run it already and the second user shouldn't zero out the data again. I think it's time to start using a database.

Comment: You could write a script to run once on those dates that kicks off the macro.

Comment: Handle the `Workbook_Open` event, and then disconnect your phone ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe time to move to access?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim dt As String

'GET THE CURRENT DAY OF MONTH
dt = Format(Now(), "DD")

'IF THE DATE IS 15th or 30th
If dt = "15" Or dt = "30" Then
    'IF THE "DONE" VALUE IS BLANK
    If Sheets(1).Range("XFD1").Value = "" Then
    'CLEAR ALL CELLS IN SHEET 1
    Sheets(1).Cells.Clear
    'SET VALUE TO "DONE" SO THE MACRO KNOWS THE DATA WIPE HAS ALREADY BEEN PERFORMED
    Sheets(1).Range("XFD1").Value = "DONE"
End If
End If

'IF THE DATE IS NOT 15TH OR 30TH, CLEAR THE "DONE" VALUE SO THE MACRO CAN RUN AGAIN THE NEXT TIME
If dt <> "15" And dt <> "30" Then
Sheets(1).Range("XFD1").Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you. Will implement and see how it works. Appreciate your help.